# How long do concealment bonuses last?

Tags: xcom-2

In the case of a ranger with the following abilities how long does the bonus from shadow strike and overwatch in concealment last?  Is it the first shot only, the whole attack, or the whole turn?

1. Rapid fire
2. Kill zone  (cross class skill)
3. Serial (cross class skill)

Comment: I believe it's only until the "revealed" popup shows, which is usually the first shot.

Comment: @BlueRaja I don't think(hope) that's the case because then setting a squad on concealed overwatch would be pointless.

Comment: Why would it be pointless?  I want my characters to be on overwatch in case I'm revealed this turn, but if I'm not I don't want them opening fire when the enemies change position on their turn.

Comment: You don't suffer an aim penalty when on concealed overwatch but if they lose their concealment status when you intentionally engage and the squad gets exposed what is the point of having that bonus?

Comment: @z': Notice that **Overwatch** and **Overwatch (Concealed)** are two separate skills. It just so happens you only get access to one based on whether you're in concealment or not. By setting your units to Overwatch (Concealed), their reaction shot from that overwatch will not get an aim penalty. So even if you set up concealed overwatch, take a shot, lose concealment, activate the pod and _then_ take the overwatch shots, they will still not have the aim penatly because it's a different skill altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *shadowstrike* bonus only counts while you're concealed. I have seen allegedly guaranteed sword attacks from concealment miss after the ranger is spotted before arriving and loses the bonus. Your soldier will be revealed after the first shot of Rapid Fire.

The overwatch bonus from an ambush lasts until the end of the XCOM turn, I think.

Kill Zone will never fire from concealment in the current version of the game, though I know that wasn't true when this was asked.

Comment: While kill zone won't fire from concealment, I can break concealment with an attack to force the enemy to move, which will trigger kill zone.  In that case, do I get the bonus similar to overwatch concealment?

Comment: @lI sure. Actually, I'm not sure Kill Zone takes the overwatch penalty anyway.